# How do I use JSONObject in Android

Tags: android

I have the following Android java code:

```
String json = "{\"Name_1\":1,\"Name_2\":0,\"Name_3\":0}";
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
String[] propertyNames = JSONObject.getNames(object);
values = new String[propertyNames.length];
for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
  values[i] = String.valueOf(object.get(propertyNames[i]));
}
```

but I am getting the following error: The method `getNames(JSONObject)` is undefined for the type `JSONObject`.
What can I do to get the `propertyNames`?

Comment: why not look at the JavaDoc? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: "What can I do to get the propertyNames?" - Use `object.names()` NOT `getNames(...)` which, as you've discovered, is an undefined method for `JSONObject`. Also note that instead of defining `propertyNames` as `String[]` use `JSONArray` instead.

Comment: then how will i get values = {"1", "0", "0"}

Answer (score 2):

Why not look at the [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)? It tells you about the [keys()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) method.

```
for (Iterator<String> it = object.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String key = it.next();
    // ...
}
```

Edit: get an array of keys:

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Iterator<String> it = object.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    String key = it.next();
    keyList.add(key);
}

String[] keyArray = keyList.toArray(new String[keyList.size()]);
```

Comment: Ridcully, what if i want key to be an array of strings?

Comment: You'd have to create one based on the loop in my example. The Iterator construct doesn't provide a simple solution here, as it's also used for situations where the results are produced on the fly and not known in advance. You could however add the keys you get during the looping to a List and and invoke the list's `toArray` method afterwards. See edited answer.